# Simple haskell splitlist

Tags: haskell

I have the following function which takes a list and returns two sublists split at a given element n. However, I only need to split it in half, with odd length lists having a larger first sublist

```
splitlist :: [a] -> Int -> ([a],[a])
splitlist [] = ([],[])
splitlist l@(x : xs) n | n > 0     = (x : ys, zs)
               | otherwise = (l, [])
    where (ys,zs) = splitlist xs (n - 1)
```

I know I need to change the signature to [a] -> ([a],[a]), but where in the code should I put something like length(xs) so that I don't break recursion?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090347/haskell-novice-trouble-with-splitting-a-list-in-half

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it using take and drop:

```
splitlist :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
splitlist [] = ([],[])
splitlist l  = let half = (length(l) +1)`div` 2
               in (take half l, drop half l)
```

or you can take advantage of the function splitAt:

```
splitlist list = splitAt ((length (list) + 1) `div` 2) list
```

Answer (score 11):

In a real program you should probably use

```
splitlist :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitlist xs = splitAt ((length xs + 1) `div` 2) xs
```

(i.e. something along the lines of dreamcrash's answer.)

But if, for learning purposes, you're looking for an explicitly recursive solution, study this:

```
splitlist :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitlist xs = f xs xs where
    f (y : ys) (_ : _ : zs) =
        let (as, bs) = f ys zs
        in (y : as, bs)
    f (y : ys) (_ : []) = (y : [], ys)
    f ys [] = ([], ys)
```

Comment: Btw, I don't if it is because I am compiling on codepad, but length xs + 1 'div' 2 it is necessary to put length (xs + 1) 'div' 2

Comment: No, it's because I didn't test my code. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: The tortoise-and-hare solution is quite a lot better than the `splitAt`-based one if the list is long. It performs one pass instead of two, and it produces the first component lazily. I'm not sure why you recommend the other implementation.

Comment: @dreamcrash Make that ``(length xs + 1) `div` 2`` (you can add 1 to a list't :-).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the take and drop built-in functions. But if you want something that can be done with all self written functions try this:

```
dropList :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
dropList 0 [] = []
dropList 0 (x:xs) = x:xs
dropList y [] = []
dropList y (x:xs) = dropList (y-1) xs

takeList :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
takeList 0 [] = []
takeList 0 (x:xs) = []
takeList y [] = []
takeList y (x:xs) 
  | y <= length (x:xs) =  x : takeList (y-1) xs
  | otherwise = []

split :: Int -> [Int] -> ([Int],[Int])
split 0 [] = ([],[])
split y [] = ([],[])
split y (x:xs) = (takeList y (x:xs), dropList y (x:xs))

main = do
  print (split 4 [1,2,3,4,5,6])
```